# How to execute a file everytime before opening Vim

Tags: vim, vi

I have recently started using vim and I really like it. I have added a few easy mappings in my vimrc file.

But the problem is I get to use a  lot of remote machines a lot of time and I can't copy my vimrc on to them but most of the times I won't have enough permissions to do that.

So, I was wondering if there is any way I can put all my vim mappings in a file and tell vim to run it every time it loads, just like a vimrc?

Comment: your requirement is not very clear to me. 1) you want  all your machines to have different vimrcs, but keep the same mappings in your "file"? 2) Do you want all your ssh-servers to have same vimrc file? 3) you said you don't have permissions to cp file on to your target servers, do you have permission to change the vimrc on the servers? or some script sourced by `bashrc` for example, so that you can create vim alias? 4) If 2) is true, what config do you still have except for the mappings? are there server specific settings/functions/plugins?

Comment: @Kent , I don't have permissions to change the vimrc file. But, i want to have the same key combinations that i have set in my vimrc.

Comment: I am a little confused as well. If you cannot change any files on the server where do you intend to load the mappings from? If you can change the files, why not change your .vimrc?

Comment: I am not exactly sure what there is here to get confused. Not all the users have access to edit vimrc files. I get access only to a few particular directories. Not the home directory. So, i can't modify the vimrc without sudo access which i don't have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The action that is "parsing" the .vimrc is called `source`.

In runtime, you can reapply/reparse your .vimrc by using

```
  :source ~/.vimrc
```

So if you can somehow copy your .vimrc, even if not in your home, but a folder like /tmp you should be able to source it from there, with

```
:source /tmp/.vimrc
```

This [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/33423/how-to-bring-vimrc-around-when-i-ssh) has more details and solutions.

Comment: Thanks mate. That's so simple.

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to specify an alternative `.vimrc` file while launching the program.

The vim man pages has this to say about specifying a vimrc file:

> `-u {vimrc}`
>   Use  the  commands  in  the file {vimrc} for initializations.  All the other initializations are skipped.  Use this
>   to edit a special kind of files.  It can also be used to skip all
>   initializations by giving the name "NONE".
>                      See ":help initialization" within vim for more details.

Note that this option overrides the default `vimrc` file, so you'll have to specify all of your settings/options in this file.

As was mentioned in another answer, you can place your custom vimrc file anywhere you want (or have access to) and then specify the the `-u` option with the path to your vimrc file.

You could even combine this method with managing your custom vimrc file in an online version control system (like github) - this way you will be able to wget your file from the web instead of having to manually copy it from machine to machine.